# Websphere portal deactivate portal pages

Tags: websphere-portal

When I start the Websphere Portal console and go to Manage Pages, I see a whole bunch of Portal pages in Active Status. Basically these are IBM internal portlet pages. I do not use them. Is there any way to safely Deactivate at least some of these portlets? The goal is to save on startup time of the portal server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options for this. The first link is for Portal light mode and the second one talks about developer mode. Both do similar things but developer mode loads fewer things on start up.

Also, having a page active or disabled shouldn't affect startup time. Preventing portlet applications from starting on startup will help though. You used both terms in your question so I want to make sure that was clear and you don't disable the pages expecting improvements.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+WebSphere+Portal+8+Product+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Using_portal_light_mode_wp8&content=pdcontent

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+WebSphere+Portal+8+Product+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Changing_to_developer_mode_wp8&content=pdcontent